# Identify matrix $A$ describing the sequence defined by $F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}$, $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, discrete-mathematics

A sequence of numbers are given by:
$F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}$, $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$
this can be expressed in Matrix form:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    F_{k+2} \\
    F_{k+1} \\
\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}
    F_{k+1} \\
    F_{k} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Find the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A?$

From the initial values I have: $\begin{bmatrix}
    F_{k+2}=1 \\
    F_{k+1}=0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}
    F_{k+1}=1 \\
    F_{0}=0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ thus$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ but I have no Idea how to proceed from here as matrix division does not exist I was taught.

Comment: This is the Fibonacci sequence, look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form.

Comment: The matrix A describes the **dynamics** of the sequence and you turn to the **initial conditions** to identify A? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Let's call the matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then we must have

$$ \begin{pmatrix} F_{k + 2} \\ F_{k + 1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a F_{k+1} + b F_{k} \\ c F_{k+1} + d F_{k} \end{pmatrix}. $$

Can you choose $a,b,c,d$ so that the equality above will hold?

Comment: I chose a=1,b=0,c=0,,d=0 did the multiplication and this yields [1,0]transpose is this correct or am I still missing something?

Comment: If you choose $a = 1, b = c = d = 0$ then you get the equations $F_{k+2} = F_{k+1}$ and $F_{k+1} = 0$. Those equations do not hold for all $k$ so you need to choose different values of $a,b,c,d$. Another hint: The second equation is "silly" while the first equation should reflect the definition of the Fibonnaci sequence.

Comment: Thank you i see what you mean now